# PHP YAZ installation on xampp

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

I have added PHP YAZ as extension into XAMPP following steps in the latest comment here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.yaz.php but when I check for YAZ section in PHPINFO, I do not have YAZ section there. Can somebody try to install it check if it is only my problem or there is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all installation tutorials, it appears that even though the extension can be enabled just by adding DLL file into `ext` folder but it is necessary to add other DLL files, except `php_*.dll` where `*` is name of the extension, into `apache\bin\` folder. Then restart server and in phpinfo you should have new extension section.